# milliseconds to string/date format

Tags: python, datetime

I am getting the date object :

```
now = datetime.utcnow()
print(now)

2017-02-09 14:00:31.256382
```

Then, making a string representation:

```
to_string = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")  
print(to_string)

2017-02-09 14:00:31.256382 (it is a str object)
```

I convert it to seconds:

```
sec = now.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()
print(sec)

1486648831.256382
```

1) I am trying to get back the string representation:

```
back = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f", time.gmtime(x))
print(back)

2017-02-09 14:00:31.%f
```

I can't figure how to represent the milliseconds.Note, also that `timestamp` returns seconds and not milliseconds.

2) If I want to get back from seconds(or milliseconds in my case) to the date object not the string object?

Comment: About the ms in the string representation: I think you wanted `now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")` instead of `time.strftime`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `utcfromtimestamp` method.

```
from datetime import datetime

ts = 1486648831.256382
print (datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts))
>>> 2017-02-09 14:00:31.256382
```

> classmethod datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp)
>
> Return the UTC datetime corresponding to the POSIX timestamp, with
>   tzinfo None. This may raise ValueError, if the timestamp is out of the
>   range of values supported by the platform C gmtime() function. It’s
>   common for this to be restricted to years in 1970 through 2038. See
>   also fromtimestamp().

The returned object is `<class 'datetime.datetime'>`

Comment: Ok, thanks!As for the milliseconds, it doesn't matter that timestamp returns seconds,since you can represent the string as you want,right?